# What's the difference between php://input and php://stdin

Tags: php, sockets, io, stdout, stdin

Similarly what is the difference between `php://output` and `php://stdout`?

I was trying to figure out how servers provide `php://input` and `php://output`. The only way I could think of (given that both `php://input` and `php://output` are independent of the mysterious php.ini file according to [this page in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)) would be to change `stdin` and `stdout` to both refer to the connection socket's file descriptor. But then to my chagrin I found out that `php://stdin` and `php://stdout` were also defined - presumably in a different way.

Is this just redundancy or do these file names actually refer to do different things? Can someone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php you can read all about it here, it specifically references the differences between these

Comment: @NicRobertson That's actually the same page I reference in my question. The page says that "`php://stdin`, `php://stdout` and `php://stderr` allow direct access to the corresponding input or output stream of the PHP process." Then it says "`php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body." Isn't that the same as stdin? Then even more confusing the document says "`php://output` is a write-only stream that allows you to write to the output buffer mechanism in the same way as print and echo." Which really seems to imply stdout and output are the same.

Comment: Questions that are explained in the documentation should state the reason/point where they are not understood. An answer that would repeat the documentation is not helpful.

Comment: @Sven I am of the opinion this is not covered in the documentation. input and stdin both have the same permissions and (in the absence of caching) refer to the same file descriptor. How these are different is not covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is in the environment where you're expected to use them. `php://stdin`, `php://stdout`, and `php://stderr` are mapped directly to the relevant [POSIX file streams](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html) and are intended for use with the CLI SAPI. On the other hand, `php://input` and `php://output` are intended for use with web-based SAPIs.

Try running these two commands from the command line:

```
printf "foo" | php -r "var_dump(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));"

printf "foo" | php -r "var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));"
```

You're going to get output like this:

```
Command line code:1:
string(3) "foo"

Command line code:1:
string(0) ""
```

Because `php://input` expects to be used by a web SAPI like CGI or mod_php and will not get the contents of STDIN passed to it. Likewise, trying to read raw POST data (the only real use for `php://input`) using `php://stdin` would fail.

`php://output` can generally be used in both environments but it's rarely used at all, since one can simply `echo` output. `php://stdout` is the more logical choice for command line code, though again it's generally easier to just use `echo`.

`php://stderr` is of course invaluable to command line programmers who need to output informational, debug, or error messages to a different stream than the program output.